# Can I make the file descriptor limit a per-thread limit?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on a Centos-6 x86_64 machine. By default, if I start a process, it can open 1024 files (including the standard in/out/error streams) and I am able to extend that limit using `setrlimit()` APIs.

My problem is that if I start a thread within the process, it shares this limit. For example, assume I am running a parent process which opens 1024 descriptors, and then if I create one thread using `pthread_create()`, it can't open a single file because its parent already opened 1024 descriptors and consumed the full limit.

I want to make the child thread (not child process) able to open 1024 files like its parent. I know that extending parent's file descriptor limit to 2048 will allow the child to open 1024 more files.  But I want to make the parent and child have individual limits, not a shared limit.

I am expecting some attributes in `pthread_attr_t` that can be applicable for the child thread to have an individual file table.

Comment: Time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Could you explain your comment? This question appears to be reasonable. It is a programming question. Its question is clear; it asks about separating system-imposed file descriptor limits between threads. No reproducible example is needed because it is not asking what is wrong with existing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux,

```
unshare(CLONE_FILES);
```

(if successful) will give the current thread its own filedescriptor table.

It should be usable from an already- spawned kernel-backed (all Linux pthreads implementations I know of) pthread.

There doesn't appear to be even a nonportable pthread attribute that you could set this up with, but you can use the above approach to wrap `pthread_create`, adding this capability.

If you're doing your own threading on Linux, you can pass the `CLONE_FILES` flag directly to `clone`. Otherwise you'll need the to make your `wrapped_pthread_create` wait until the child has made the `unshare` call (and cancel and reap the thread if the call failed).

Comment: Note that after unsharing the file descriptor table, you'll have to close all the descriptors in the thread that it doesn't need access to, in order to free up those descriptors.